# gitlab rule: prevent running on specific path

Tags: gitlab, rules

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules

In Gitlab, rules replaces only/except keywords.

My repos have always some src code, Dockerfile, ... and documentation: md files and .docs folder.
My pipelines run some build job on the repo.
If only the documentation is changed, I don't want my pipeline to run

I wrote the following:

```
.never_for_md_or_docs: &never_for_md_or_docs
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
      changes:
        - "**/*.md"
        - "**/docs/*"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

I want my pipeline to run normally BUT when either a .md file or anything in the docs folder is changed.

It does not do what I expected: it always prevent the pipeline to run on main.
What is wrong here? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> it always prevent the pipeline to run on main

Another rule `when: always` is required to trigger it.

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
      changes:
        - "**/*.md"
        - "**/docs/*"
      when: never

    - when: always
```

Comment: thanks. I however forgot to mention that I have other rules below. I edit my question

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs on `rules:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules):

> Rules are evaluated when the pipeline is created, and evaluated *in order* until the first match. When a match is found, the job is either included or excluded from the pipeline, depending on the configuration.

and

> The job is added to the pipeline:
>
> - If an if, changes, or exists rule matches and also has `when: on_success` (default), `when: delayed`, or `when: always`.
> - If a rule is reached that is only `when: on_success`, `when: delayed`, or `when: always`.

So it seems like you need:

```
.never_for_md_or_docs: &never_for_md_or_docs
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
      changes:
        - "**/*.md"
        - "**/docs/*"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: always
```